# pgrouting no result // topology problem

Tags: pgrouting, topology, dijkstra, vehicle-routing-problem

First of all, I am new to map making, and I am mostly relying on tutorials to learn. As part of a project, I am making an airway map using QGIS and I do it by uploading the points with lat/long thru a csv file, and then connect them thru Points2One plugin. After that, I used pgrouting to create topology and calculate shortest path with dijkstra. However, when input the start and end points for calculation, the pgr_dijkstra won't return anything unless I used the "source" and "target" points. Below is the route network:

If I use point 5 & 6, it will yield result since in the table, there are the source and target. but if I use 29 and 23, it won't give result.

Is pgr_djikstra supposed to work like that? Anything that I am doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image: yields one result]

[image: no result]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT 3:**
*After a long discussion in the comments I reviewed my answer, taking the sample data and it´s upload into PostgreSQL from within QGIS into account. I deleted my* EDIT 2 *as it became useless.*

The problem is that you initially run `pgr_dijkstra` on **multilinestrings**. Next to the topology (that you created), the basic geometric structure for any *pgRouting* function to run the way it should is to have a properly noded network, **consisting of simple linestrings instead**, defined by two nodes (-> `source`, `target`).
*pgRouting* has the built in [pgr_nodeNetwork](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/common/doc/functions/node_network.html) function to do just that for you (albeit with possible drawbacks, see EDIT 1). In order to get expected results:

- run data import: in the GUI, check the box '*Create single-part geometries instead of multi-part*' to create the table *yourtablename*.
  Note: at this point you can also project your data into a CRS suitable for your region of interest, to have all further calculations and their outputs in *meter* instead of *(decimal) degrees*. This will affect the tolerance settings I used below.
- run `pgr_nodeNetwork`: create a noded network from your **initial set of linestrings** (Note: the function does not keep any attributes, it will add an *old_id* column instead to refer to your initial data!). Since your data is in EPSG:4326, use a low tolerance in degrees to treat nearby vertices as equal:
  `SELECT pgr_nodeNetwork('<yourtablename>', 0.00001, 'id', 'geom');`
- run `pgr_createTopology`: create the topology reference with the **noded network table created above** (usually called *yourtablename_noded*):
  `SELECT pgr_createTopology('<yourtablename_noded>', 0.00001, 'geom');`
- run `pgr_dijkstra`: calculate shortest path between nodes **on the same noded network table** *yourtablename_noded*.
  **Note:** you have to refer to the **created vertice table** *yourtablename_noded_vertices_pgr* for the start and end points of your desired route (e.g. visualize that table in QGIS and pick the *source/target* vertice ids to route from/to)!
  `JOIN` those with the *yourtablename_noded* table and the original table to get your route with combined columns:

```
SELECT route.*,
       original.*
FROM pgr_dijkstra(
        'SELECT id,
                old_id,
                source,
                target,
                ST_Length(geom) AS cost
         FROM <yourtablename_noded>',
         29, 96,
         FALSE
) AS route
JOIN <yourtablename_noded> AS edges
  ON route.edge = edges.id
JOIN <yourtablename> AS original
  ON original.id = edges.old_id;
```

**EDIT 1:** 
As @dkastl pointed out, `pgr_nodeNetwork` does try to split the given network at every intersection found, which might be undesirable for many cases, e.g. where two lines visually intersect but thematically should be treated as not intersecting (consider bridges in road networks [thanks to @dkastl]).
The more general rule here should be to make sure the network you want to route on consists of simple linestrings with nodes only at desired intersections, and *pgr_nodeNetwork* being a tool to achieve that efficiently if no intersection restrictions occur.

Comment: Be careful with recommending `pgr_nodeNetwork`, because this will create nodes at intersections, which may be wrong (ie. bridges)!
Second, pgRouting will automatically only care about the first linestring in a multilinestring, if that geometry type is used. So this shouldn't be the problem, but you're correct, that having linestring geometry type is the only one, that makes sense.
Running `pgr_createTopology` makes sense, because it seems that there is something wrong with it.

Comment: @dkastl good catch with *pgr_nodeNetwork*...I will edit that into my answer. however, taking only the first linepart into account should very well be the problem, since then there might simply be no connection/possible path between the routing *source* and *target* ([5, 6] might be found along the same multiline since it's defined as it's *source/target* nodes, [29, 23] however is supposedly across multiple multilines with their (wrongly assigned) nodes not necessary connected)

Comment: @ThingumaBob I used the `pgr_nodeNetwork` but its giving me a FAIL result. I don't know why. So I tried to test intersecting lines containing only 2 points, but it still shows MULTILINESTING in the geom column when I upload. I tried using the `pgr_nodeNetwork` but still gives a FAIL result. Are there any conditions to fulfill for the database to upload my data as a LINESTRING?

Comment: @Vnox ah yeah...damn, there were times when I gave consistent answers in the first place...okay, so you need to use `ST_Dump` to partition each *MULTILINESTRING* into it´s *LINESTRINGS*. I will update my answer with a query to include referrences to the initial *MULTILINESTRING*...

Comment: @ThingumaBob yes I created a topology first. But still gives same result. I tried the code that you gave me (thank you btw), `pgr_createTopology` runs fine, but the resulting table is blank. Also, `pgr_nodeNetwork` still gives FAIL.

Comment: @Vnox updated the answer, try again with the query. I added the *PRIMARY KEY* to the *uid* column since `pgr_createTopology` requres a unique constraint. `pgr_createTopology` will only add values to the 'network' table's *source/target* columns and creates a seperate vertices table. also: what CRS do you use? I assume one with meters as unit (ooposed to degree) in my function call.

Comment: @ThingumaBob I use EPSG:4326 which use meters. source and target columns are all [0, 0]. `pgr_createTopology` still returns blank. Do you think maybe because of the process of how I do the map itself?

Comment: @Vnox could you upload sampledata maybe? also, EPSG:4326 (WGS84) uses (decimal) degrees! use a tolerance of sth  around 0.000001 instead (being roughly around 11cm at the equator)

Comment: @ThingumaBob [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkZJLSZsDMf5hniFAiTFpRe_gBv3) here is my sample waypoints data. I plot it in QGIS and uns the _Points2One_ plugin to draw the lines that I import to the database

Comment: @Vnox okay thx. I tested them and it worked just fine. I reviewed my answer to detail the steps I took. two things: I used *pgr_nodeNetwork* successfully, but with some lines not being treated as intersecting. after you created the topology, load both the *yourtablename_noded* table and the *yourtablename_noded_vertices_pgr* table into QGIS to verify, if there`s no vertice on an intersection, those lines are not connected. Then, to actually use dijkstra you will need to use the vertice ids from that *yourtablename_noded_vertices_pgr* table as start/end points! I forgot to mention that earlier.

Comment: @ThingumaBob now it's working! Apparently, I was adding _source_ and _target_ column before I use the `pgr_nodeNetwork` which i think is the cause why it's failing (tested it couple of times). Also, I made a slight modification on your code as follows: `JOIN myTable_noded AS original
  ON original.id = edges.id;`, because if I use the original table, the resulting geometry will draw the whole _LINESTRING_ from the table, i.e. the whole airway, resulting in incorrect visualization. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with pgr_nodenetwork, so I looked at the known issues.  It seems that pgr_nodenetwork has not been working properly [see here](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/280).  To overcome these issues, I manually noded my network before running

```
drop table if exists in_edges_int;
create table in_edges_int as
select * from (
select a.id, b.id as int_id, (st_dump(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom))).geom from in_edges a, in_edges b where a.id != b.id and st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)) foo
where st_geometrytype(geom) = 'ST_LineString';

drop table if exists in_edges_split;

create table in_edges_split as
select a.id, (st_dump(st_split(st_segmentize(a.geom,1),st_union(b.geom)))).geom as geom 
from in_edges a, in_edges_int b where b.id = a.id and st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom) group by a.id;

insert into in_edges_split (id, geom) 
select id, geom from in_edges where not st_intersects(geom,(select st_union(geom) from in_edges_int));
```

You'll need to re-join any attributes you need after this as all your left with is id and geom columns (or you can add the columns you need into the queries above).